# Problems showing JS Modals with Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm trying to use modals for Rails flash messages, for the output of :notices or :errors. I just want to show them, when the page is changed, but I only can get them to work, when the document is loaded. But then it is always active.

In the application.html.erb I use:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
        <div id="modal1" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p><%= msg %></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my application.js file I use:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
    var modal1 = document.getElementById('#modal1');

    if (modal1.length > 0) {
        $('#modal1').openModal();
    }
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

I tried checking if the string is not null too, or the length is greater zero but this won't change a thing. Only if I use:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
    $('#modal1').openModal();
}
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

it works, but then it is shown every time a page is reloaded, whether a flash msg is shown or not, and I don't want this behavior. When I change to `$(document).on('page:change', ready);` then the window stays darkened after clicking on the modal close button.

I use materializecss for this, if that helps.

Why do those checks not work? I tried different if statements and checks but all resulted in the modal not being showed. Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards.

For those who want to know how it works. There was 1) an error in the js code and 2) I had to use a different logic for if then.

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
var modal1 = document.getElementById('modal1');
if (modal1 !== null) {
    $('#modal1').openModal();
}
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: This line contains an error: `var modal1 = document.getElementById('#modal1');` You need to remove the `#`, like this: `var modal1 = document.getElementById('modal1');`.  I'm not sure why you're using raw JavaScript there anyway, when you're using jQuery elsewhere...

Comment: Thank you @dwenzel. I corrected the error and changed the if logic, too. Because `length > 0` does not work, as the var results in `[object HTMLDivElement]` I chose `modal1 !== null`. And this way everything works as it should.

The reason why I mix raw js with jquery is simple. My knowledge on the topic is not broad enough and as I am succeeding with my projects I will get to know jquery better and maybe make better use of it. :)

Thank you.